# Python variable scoping in nested function calls

Tags: python, variables, scope

I come to this [code](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-splitted-binary-tree/solutions/496549/java-c-python-easy-and-concise/https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-splitted-binary-tree/solutions/496549/java-c-python-easy-and-concise/) in a LeetCode problem

```
class Solution:
    def maxProduct(self, root):
        self.res = total = 0

        def s(root):
            if not root: return 0
            left, right = s(root.left), s(root.right)
            self.res = max(self.res, left * (total - left), right * (total - right))
            return left + right + root.val

        total = s(root)
        s(root)
        return self.res % (10**9 + 7)
```

I change `self.res` to `res` like the following

```
class Solution:
    def maxProduct(self, root):
        res = total = 0

        def s(root):
            if not root: return 0
            left, right = s(root.left), s(root.right)
            res = max(res, left * (total - left), right * (total - right))
            return left + right + root.val

        total = s(root)
        s(root)
        return res % (10**9 + 7)
```

and the code breaks with `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment`. Why `res` has to be initialized as `self.res` while `total` does not?

Comment: Please update your question with the alternate code where you `"change self.res to res"` and the corresponding full error traceback to help us understand what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I think that in this case you will need `nonlocal res` just inside `def s(root):`. This extensive [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXugs4B3lwU&t=1004s) by mCoding explains the scoping rules in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why res has to be initialized as self.res while total does not?

It does not, but because of the rules of Python's *implicit declarations*, by default *assignment is declaration*.

Since `s` only *reads* from `total`, it necessarily has to come from somewhere else, but because of

```
 res = max(self.res, left * (total - left), right * (total - right))
```

Python will create a `res` variable which is local to `s`, so you really have two different variables with the same name, one in `maxProduct` and one in `s`. This is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

You can tell Python that a variable being assigned to is not a local by explicitly declaring it so:

```
nonlocal res
```

This will make Python assign to the lexically closest variable of that name:

```py
def foo():
    a = 1
    def bar():
        a = 2
    bar()
    print(a)

foo()
# 1

def foo():
    a = 1
    def bar():
        nonlocal a
        a = 2
    bar()
    print(a)

foo()
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the nested function `s` has it's own variable scope.
While it can read variables (like `res`) from the enclosing scope (`maxProduct`),
any assignment (e.g. `res = max(...)`)
will introduce a variable in the scope of `s`, instead of
writing to the outer (`res`).
Because in this case `maxProduct` wants to read the *modified* version of res
that `s` produced, the trick of adding a member variable to self is used.
(In that case, `s` only **reads** the reference to self, and then adds a member, avoiding the scope issue).

See this little example for demonstration:

```
def foo():
        def bar():
                x=2
        x=1
        bar()
        return x
```

`foo()` returns 1, not 2, because, the assignment to `x` in `bar` introduces a new variable in the scope of `bar`